# Ubuntu 20.04 switched my display size to 1024x768 when it should be 1366x768 and it isnt showing that it has that res available

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I restarted my PC around 30 minutes ago and before it was in 13366x768, which is normal, that's the correct display size for my monitor, but when I restarted it it was stretched and in 1024x768 and when I went to change this in the display settings it only showed that i had 4:3 1024x768 and nothing else. Can anyone help me? I use a NVIDIA GTX 1050 and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: On a real machine or a virtualbox? Please add the output of `inxi -G`to your question (copy and paste)

Comment: sorry it took me a long time to get back to use, I just had to restart my pc a couple of times